# Show Only one address on checkout/#shipping page

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

How to limit the address on `checkout/#shipping` page. like all the address from `cutomer_address_entity` are listed in this page. but how to show only one address.

I have added a quote programmatically, and add address for that quote programmatically. now i want to show that quote address (which i added against that quote id programmatically) show on shipping page. instead it shows all the addresses from `customer_address_entity` table.

Answer (score 0):

For that, you have to override the default Magento below file.

> vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\js\view\shipping-address\list.js

inside this file add the below logic.

```
initChildren: function () {

        if(addressList().length > 0){
           // Add your logic as per your requirement.
            this.createRendererComponent(addressList()[0],this);
        }
        else{
            _.each(addressList(), this.createRendererComponent, this);
        }

        return this;
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: But it will show only the first address from list. i have update my question. Please have a look.